# Проверить наличие записей

Tags: sql, oracle, инспекция-кода, oracle12c

Есть три таблицы

- clusters (id....)
- points (id, cluster_id, ...)
- data (id, point_id, ....)

Нужно выбрать какие-то записи из `clusters` и указать есть ли для этого кластера записи в `data`

Пишу

```sql
SELECT
  cls.*,
  CASE
    WHEN EXISTS (
      SELECT
        1
      FROM
        points pt
        JOIN data dt ON pt.id = dt.point_id
      WHERE
        pt.cluster_id = cls.id
        AND dt....  -- Какие-то условия налагаемые на записи в data
    ) THEN 1
    ELSE NULL
  END AS DATA_EXISTS
FROM
  clusters cls
WHERE
  cls....
```

В другом месте мне нужно вывести записи из `points` и тоже с признаком наличия записей в `data`

```sql
SELECT
  pt.*,
  CASE
    WHEN EXISTS (
      SELECT
        1
      FROM
        data dt
      WHERE
        dt.point_id = pt.id
        AND dt....  -- Какие-то условия налагаемые на записи в data
    ) THEN 1
    ELSE NULL
  END AS DATA_EXISTS
FROM
  points pt
WHERE
  pt....
```

`Какие-то условия налагаемые на записи в data` всегда одни и те же, но могут меняться по мере развития проекта. Поэтому захотелось написать отдельную функцию, которая будет проверять наличие записей

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SF_E_DATA_EXISTS(
  in_point_id IN NUMBER 
) RETURN NUMBER
AS
  var_res NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT
    CASE
      WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT
          1
        FROM
          data dt
        WHERE
          dt.point_id = in_point_id
          AND dt....  -- Какие-то условия налагаемые на записи в data
        )
      THEN 1
      ELSE NULL
    END
  INTO
    var_res
  FROM
    dual;
  RETURN var_res;
END SF_E_DATA_EXISTS;
```

И вызывать ее в запросах. Тогда первый запрос принимает вид

```sql
SELECT
  cls.*,
  CASE
    WHEN EXISTS (
      SELECT
        1
      FROM
        points pt
      WHERE
        pt.cluster_id = cls.id AND
        SF_E_DATA_EXISTS(pt.id) IS NOT NULL
    ) THEN 1
    ELSE NULL
  END AS DATA_EXISTS
FROM
  clusters cls
WHERE
  cls....
```

Вопросы: на сколько адекватно решение? И сильно ли я ухудшил план запроса? Может есть что-то альтернативное?

Comment: «... условия налагаемые на записи в data всегда одни и те же, но могут меняться ...» Пробовали использовать для этих целей view? Не знаю насчет производительности, но, возможно, читать view было бы удобнее чем функцию.

Comment: @defaultlocale В смысле читать оптимизатору? Интересная идея

Comment: Читать людям :) Насчет оптимизатора не знаю точно.

Comment: По моему, действительно, view будет достаточно. Функция здесь не упрощает, не улучшает, не ускоряет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В "голом" SQL аналогом функций являются VIEW, как правильно сказали в комментариях (тем более что PL/SQL функции еще и переключения контекста будут вызывать, а это никогда на пользу не идет).

Кажется, в данном случае будет достаточно сделать простое вью типа такого:

```
create or replace view conditional_data as
select *
  from data
 where dt....  -- Какие-то ваши условия, налагаемые на записи в data
```

Тогда запрос к `points` превращается в:

```
SELECT
  pt.*,
  CASE
    WHEN EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
        FROM conditional_data dt
       WHERE dt.point_id = pt.id
    ) THEN 1
    ELSE NULL
  END AS DATA_EXISTS
FROM
  points pt
WHERE
  pt....
```

Аналогично в запросе к `clusters` вы делаете подзапрос, внутри которого джойните `points` и `data`. Этот подзапрос тоже можно вынести во VIEW, и он будет ссылаться на предыдущее VIEW, типа такого:

```
SELECT *
  FROM points pt
     JOIN conditional_data dt ON pt.id = dt.point_id
```

Если же вам в рамках одного запроса нужно использовать некий подзапрос в нескольких местах, а лишнее VIEW создавать не хочется ради одного запроса, то есть второй способ - завернуть в `with` и вынести. Например:

```
with subquery as (
    select ... from ... where ...)
select ...
  from subquery, table1, table2 ...
 where ...
 union all
select ...
  from subquery, table3, table4 ...
 where ...
```